# How to get a C/C++ variable's property

Tags: c++, c, variables, scope

How do I get the property of a variable?

Example:

```
int a = 5;
....
....
isConstant(a); //Prints "no!" if 'a' is not a constant at this time.
isRegister(a); //Prints "yes!" if 'a' is a register at this time.important.
isVolatile(a); //Prints "trusted" if 'a' is volatile.
isLocal(a);    //If it is temporary.
isStatic(a);   //Static?
```

I have only read about changing constantness of a variable but not the others.

Comment: Probably not possible in C++.

Comment: Most of this is just not possible (and most of it is also worthless).

Comment: You can't change the constness of a variable. You can only instruct the compiler to think it's a const when it's not or the other way around. Typically this is done by using pointers.

Comment: It *may* help also if you explain *why* you need to know this. What you are asking for is not naturally a part of C++, but your overall goal may be achievable by other means.

Comment: Given that 'register' is an advisory anyway (i.e. the compiler is entitled to (and probably will) ignore it), the chances of you being able to find out if something is actually in a register is pretty low. I suspect that isLocal and isStatic could be worked out by some nasty address checking

Your snippet suggests that 'isRegister' is important in which case you may well have fairly major problems with your design anyway

Comment: `isStatic` is a little ambiguous - *which* meaning of `static` did you have in mind?

Comment: The biggest problem with `IsRegister()` is that the answer may be "It depends". E.g. it may depend on the exact CPU core.

Comment: for example: i will buy an itanium processor. will it be registers? :D

Comment: isStatic about being temporarity of any kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly just because I wanted to know if I could: You can see if something is in a register or not with a little bit of inline assembly. It asks for the same input twice, once in a register and once anywhere, either memory or register. If changing one changes both then you've been given the same register as both inputs.

The following worked on x86 and x86_64 with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>

#define isRegister(x) \
  { \
    bool result; \
    asm("notl %1; /* alter always register one */ \
         cmpl %2, %1; /* has the other changed? */ \
         sete %0; /* save to result */ \
         notl %1; /* restore */" \
        :"=&q"(result) /* out */ \
        :"r"(x), "g"(x) /* in */ \
        : /* no clobber */ \
    ); \
   std::cout << (result ? "Yes" : "No") << "\n"; \
  }

int main() {
  register int a=666;
  int b=667;
  register int c = 0;
  int d = 0;
  isRegister(a);
  isRegister(b);
  isRegister(c);
  isRegister(d);
  std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << "\n";
}
```

The use of inline asm here immediately makes it non-portable and you'd probably want to use gcc's expr-statement extension in real code which again makes this non-portable and it's a fragile hack. You'll need to be careful - aggressive optimisation can break this. That's a pretty good hint that you should leave this to the compiler rather than worrying about what's in a register or not and there's a non-zero risk that actually using this code may change the answer since it possibly takes up registers in and of itself!

Comment: wow. good. I am using digital mars C/C++ compiler. İ will check it out

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık - I really wouldn't use this in real code. I just wanted to see if I could do it!

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I just use one of the (many) online x86 instruction lists and search that.

Comment: +1 for the cool experiment, but mostly for the repeated disclaimers that it's not safe :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you can use template metaprogramming for `const` and `volatile`. IDK about `register` and I'm pretty sure you can't for `static` or local scoped variables.

In C++11 you have, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_const<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_const<const int>::value  << '\n';
}
```

prints

```
false
true
```

There's also `std::is_volatile<>`

Comment: And with `decltype` it gets pretty feasible (except `register`).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes apperently there's full support for this in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, you can determine if a variable is dynamically allocated in the heap or not. For that you need to keep track of the addresses returned by `malloc()`, `new()`/`new[]` and such. Then you can check if the address of the variable falls into any of the ranges of the currently allocated blocks of memory.

You may also be able to determine if a variable is a global/static variable or not. For that you will need to either make your program parse itself (= parse its executable) to find out where the relevant data section starts and ends or instruct the compiler/linker to create global variables at the beginning and end of the data section. Then you see if the variable's address is in that range between those variables or not.

For `const`, `volatile` and `register` modifiers you might be able to use some C++ "magic" as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather easy way to determine whether the variable is on stack (local) or on heap (global/static/allocated) - basically check wheter the variable adress is between the variable on the top of the stack and variable on the bottom of the stack. I added some testing code as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
// we want asserts to work in release as well
#undef NDEBUG
#include <cassert>

//! Address of the first variable on the stack
void* g_stackStart;

//! \return true if the address of variable is between g_stackStart and an address of the variable on the top of the stack
template <class T>
bool isLocal(const T& var)
{
    void* stackEnd;
    __asm
    {
        mov stackEnd, ESP
    }
    // what's the direction of stack?
    if ( g_stackStart > stackEnd )
    {
        return &var < g_stackStart && &var >= stackEnd;
    }
    else
    {
        return &var >= g_stackStart && &var < stackEnd;
    }
}

// test for nested variables
void nested(int arg)
{
    int local = int();
    assert( isLocal(local) );
    assert( isLocal(arg) );
}

// global variable used for testing
int global;

int main()
{ 
    // global stack begin pointer must be set here
    __asm
    {
        mov g_stackStart, EBP
    }

    int onStack = int();
    int* onHeap = new int();
    std::pair<int, int> pair(0, 0);

    assert( isLocal(onStack) );
    assert( !isLocal(*onHeap) );
    assert( isLocal(onHeap) );
    assert( !isLocal(global) );
    assert( isLocal(pair) );
    assert( isLocal(pair.first) );
    assert( isLocal(pair.second) );
    nested(0);

    delete onHeap;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously it is for single-threaded scenarios only. You could decorate g_stackStart with thread local attribute (compiler-dependand so far) and set it whenever each thread stars, but then again thread will only be able to check localness of their own variables.